# How to process and extract text from image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

I'm trying to extract text from image using python cv2. The result is pathetic and I can't figure out a way to improve my code.
I believe the image needs to be processed before the extraction of text but not sure how.

[image: Sample image]

I've tried to convert it into black and white but no luck.

```
import cv2
import os
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import time

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd='C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 8000)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 6000)

while True:
    return_value,image = cam.read()
    image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = image[127:219, 508:722]
    #(thresh, image) = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',image)
    print('Text detected: {}'.format(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.jpg'))))
    time.sleep(2)

cam.release()
#os.system('del test.jpg')
```

Comment: You could also try to use EasyOCR. In my case the results were much better compared to Tesseract where it was just random text. At the moment, a custom model using EasyOCR cannot be trained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preprocessing to clean the image before performing text extraction can help. Here's a simple approach

- Convert image to grayscale and sharpen image
- Adaptive threshold
- Perform morpholgical operations to clean image
- Invert image

---

First we convert to grayscale then sharpen the image using a [sharpening kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing))

[image]

Next we adaptive threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

Now we perform [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to smooth the image

[image]

Finally we invert the image

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, sharpen_kernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
result = 255 - close

cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: This actually helped me learn few good tricks about processing the image but still pytesseract is unable to extract any anything from the image.

Comment: You may have to "cut up" the image and feed each line into pytesseract to get good results. Slicing the image horizontally in half to separate each word could help. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this. I’ll try it and update the post.